# JDBC: Does call to rollback() method have effect only if call to commit() method does not succeed?

Tags: java, jdbc, commit, rollback

I am new to Java JDBC, and developed a small database application. I am learning from *O'Reilly - Database Programming with JDBC and Java 2nd Edition.*

Does `con.rollback()` have effect only if`con.commit` does not succeed?

I expected that calling `con.rollback()` has its effect even if `con.commit()` succeeded. In other words, utilizing it as an **"Undo"** action.

I tried calling `con.rollback()` after `con.commit()` succeeded, but it is not working as expected. So is it alright/expected?

This example is from the book I mentioned above:

The call to `con.rollback()` is commented out. It is near the end before `con.close()`. I tried uncommenting it and running it. However, `con.rollback()` doesn't roll things back after `con.commit()` succeeded.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class UpdateLogic
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Connection con = null;

        try
        {
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Company";
            Statement s;
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
            con.setAutoCommit(false); // make sure auto commit is off!
            s = con.createStatement();// create the first statement
            s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO employee VALUES ('1', 'employee 1', '22','00-1234' )");

            s.close(); // close the first statement
            s = con.createStatement(); // create the second statement
            s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO employee VALUES ('2', 'employee 2', '21','00_4321' )");

            con.commit(); // commit the two statements
            System.out.println("Insert succeeded.");
            s.close(); // close the second statement
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(UpdateLogic.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            if (con != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    con.rollback();
                } // rollback on error
                catch (SQLException i)
                {
                }
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
            if (con != null)
            {
                try
                {
                  //con.rollback();
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its hard to make out what you are asking. If a commit succeeds then its done, complete, you can't roll it back at that point. You have to mark a transaction for rollback ***before*** calling the `commit` method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you call `commit()`, you complete/close the current transaction.  Thus, since [`rollback()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#rollback%28%29) undoes any changes in the current transaction (as per the javadoc), it will effectively do nothing.

Answer (score 7):

> Is con.rollback() has effect only if con.commit not succeeded?

**YES** And It also has effect if you call it before `con.commit` . And prerequisite is that autocommit mode of connection should be false using `con.setAutoCommit(false)`
Any transaction that you make in database using `DML` SQL queries using JDBC with **[con.setAutoCommit(false)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit%28boolean%29)** is not commited to database until `con.commit()` is called. The latest commited transaction that you make in database acts as the **[savepoint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Savepoint.html)** for that connection. When you call **[con.rollback()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#rollback%28%29)** all transaction that you have done after that `savepoint` is undone. Also if some exception occurs while calling **[con.commit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit%28%29)**, it means that transactions are not saved in database. It is a good practice to call `con.rollback()` in `catch` statement if `con.commit()` fails.

Comment: Savepoints are a different but related concept: Savepoints are inside a transaction and allow you to mark points in a transaction that you can rollback to without redoing the whole transaction.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel:  So how is it different from what I mentioned in my post?

Comment: The difference is that you can have one or more Savepoints inside an active transaction.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: I have nowhere mentioned that there can't be more than one Savepoints inside active transaction..

Comment: Hi, you said "It is a good practice to call `con.rollback()` in `catch` statement if `con.commit()` fails". Is it strictly necessary? What happens if you don't do it?

Comment: @jmrodrigg: As I have mentioned in my post that con.rollback() and con.commit() shows its effect only for false mode of autocommit . Now If you are performing a set of transactions atomically and you get some error while n(>1)th transaction is performing. This will cause the control to execute catch statement. In case you don't call `con.rollback` then If at other part of your code a successful transaction is commited for the same Connection object then this will cause those half successful transactions of the unsuccessful atomic operation to commit also which will cause loss of Data integrity

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. Although it's not my scenario (I create the connection Object for each transaction, when I need it), it's good to know how it really works. thanks!